# How to get the unknown variables through voltage division?

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-divider

Given this circuit, how do I find E, Vz, and Vy when Vx is 3V?[image]

When I tried solving it, through simplification of circuits, (correct me if I'm wrong) I got a total resistance of 12k while resistance of Vy is 10k. Upon getting the total resistance, I used the voltage division formula to get E, since the formula is Vx = E(Rx/Rt) where E is the voltage source, Rx is the resistance of x and Rt is the total resistance, I manipulated it to get E, which, in my calculations, is 2.4V. Now this is where I'm confused, since E, which is the source, is less than the voltage of a resistor, did I make a mistake in my calculations? Since, from my understanding, a voltage source's voltage is always greater than the voltage of its elements? Also, can I solve it in the manner of finding Vy first, then Vz, then E? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I manipulated it to get E, which, in my calculations, is 2.4V*

That's incorrect so, just work from right to left filling out the details as you go: -

[image]

No need for any extensive analysis other than using ohm's law and writing things down.

I'm not providing a full answer, just a partial answer so you can see the method.

Comment: is there any way to answer it with voltage division though? im trying to learn the concept and i think solving it that way would make me understand this types of problems more

Comment: @AedenSchmidt sure there is. \$V_{OUT} = V_{Y}\cdot\dfrac{6k}{6k+4k}\$. Just rearrange to get Vy = 5 volts.

Comment: @Aeden You can if you want to (and if you perform the calculations correctly) but the method shown by Andy is simpler. I suggest finish solving the problem using the method above. If you want to practice using voltage dividers do it again using that method and check your answers match those obtained using the method shown above. As your known voltage is on the right you'll need to work from the right progressively working out Vy, Vz and then E. Don't try to go from Vx to E in one go because it's very easy to introduce an error in a large expression (and you need to state Vy and Vz anyway).

Comment: This answer isn't good.

Comment: @MissMulan maybe you can explain why.

Comment: @MissMulan - If you believe an answer isn't good enough to upvote it, then don't upvote it. However please note the "green tick" next to the answer - that means that the OP found the answer was good enough to solve their problem & they accepted the answer. It is fine if you disagree with the OP - it would help if you explain why. Note that site policy here, currently being discussed on Meta, is that full homework answers tend to be discouraged. Helping to show an OP the process of solving their question (e.g. by socratic questions, hints & other methods) leads to them learning more. Thanks.

Comment: @MissMulan I'm still waiting to hear your reasons and maybe you can explain the downvote too. I see you have revisited this site a few minutes ago so please do enlighten me.

Comment: @MissMulan I see you are back (on site) again and haven't explained yourself. If you want to be taken seriously as an engineer you should try and justify why you think my answer "isn't good". Based on your comment, someone created an answer that gave the full details of how to calculate "E" and, because the question is homework, we frown on full answers to homework so, you do have some responsibility in this especially as user:upali cited your comment as a reason to give his/her full answer.

Comment: It is too short and doesnt explain where do the values come from.

Comment: @Miss Mulan, V/R = I. V is already given in the question. The rest follows from it. That's all happening. It's self explanatory.

Comment: @MissMulan use your eyes and read the question. Note that this is homework so we only give partial answers to homework.

Answer (score -2):

E=15v
My full solution is here:

[image: Image of solution to the question]

Comment: Please don't hand out solutions to obvious homework problems. We don't do that here.

Comment: He asked. I gave the answer.yes my own.

Comment: Some one half answerd. So it was commented "this answer not good" . I answered. So some one say dont answer. How do we know which should answer my God. We are wasting time.

Comment: I think if some one try to learn from websites is great.

Comment: @upali - Hi, "*Some one half answerd*" Yes, deliberately. "*it was commented "this answer not good"*" That comment is an opinion. Please see my [comment above](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554086/how-to-get-the-unknown-variables-through-voltage-division/554088#comment1444826_554088) where I try to explain that, although the site community here is still discussing this, the general view is that full answers to homework tend to be discouraged. Even if the OP here did their research (and here, they did!) future readers can just copy & paste a full answer, without knowledge.

Comment: I am new to this website. I dont know fascilities here, but i like this website. Because quick answers come.

Comment: Please tell me what is the meaning of "OP" ?

Comment: @upali - "*Please tell me what is the meaning of "OP" ?*" The acronym OP = original poster (the person) or original posting (the question *text* itself) - you have to judge which one from context, when you see someone mention "OP". In my comment above, I meant the person.

Comment: @upali note that I didn't half-answer through laziness or incompetence; I half answered because the question was homework and this site doesn't give full answers to homework. If you downvoted my answer because of this, please reconsider this action because it is contrary to site customs.

Comment: @Andyaka - Hi, Regarding "*If you downvoted my answer [...]*" - FYI [downvoting privilege requires 125 points](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) so *upali* cannot (currently) downvote your answer.

Comment: You are good in solving. But you should work on spellings in English, just saying. Welcome to EESE.

Comment: Thank you Mr SamGibson. I think you have edited my answer. I uploaded the png file but only the link was visible. You have made it visible. Now I check my spellings , thank Mr. Mithu Raj. Keep in touch. This way I can correct my mistakes, I mean by answering in this website. Welcome...!Yes Mr.SamGibson I did not downvote. Just I answer to the original post. People may have various answers, that I don't downvote. The OP will choose the good answer

Comment: I don't know about this website, so please the admin may tell me is this for students assignments ? , or can we discuss anything? My idea is if users don't get good answer from this website no body would visit this. Why windows was very popular? Easy to use than dos. Some users try to control our answers. If my answer is not to be given why the admin did not delete it? Even I have earned scors. Thanks.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour @upali